# where is the timestamp() function defined

Tags: c++

I am trying to use the timestamp() function. But I don't know in which header it is defined. I tried , But it's not in there. It gives the error when compiling which is below

```
error: ‘timestamp’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: There is no `timestamp` function in standard C++. You might be looking `std::time` which is in `<ctime>`. Use it like `ts = std::time(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Do a simple search:

> grep timestamp *.h

Or recursive:

> grep -r timestamp .

(This works on a unix-like system; adjust if you work with Windows or something else)

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard `timestamp()` function. If you want to use `std::time()`, you can include the `<ctime>` header.